# angular converting the date in dd/mm/yyyy format

Tags: angularjs

i have date format getting from server in the following way,

```
"tranDate":"2015-11-29T18:30:00.000Z"
```

I tried to displaying the date in the view like this, but the date is showing - 30/11/2015(i.e it should be 29/11/2015).

```
<td>{{stmt.tranDate | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
```

what could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Angular 1.3 you can specify that you want the time to be interpreted in UTC.

```
<td>{{stmt.tranDate | date:'dd/MM/yyyy' : 'UTC'}}</td>
```

Answer (score 4):

Your time is in Zulu time (Z in the end). Angular displays time in your local time.

Answer (score 2):

Try this  `{{stmt.tranDate | date:"dd/MM/yyyy": 'UTC'}}`

Answer (score 1):

You can apply this format  then you have the desired date .

```
$scope.datex="2015-11-29T18:30:00.000Z";
  <p>{{datex | date:'d/M/yyyy'}}</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try with moment.js and with tha `angular-moment` directive